# Using CASE WHEN statements (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

Struggling with a case when statement (MySQL) and its probably something simple I am missing.

I have a fairly complex query which outputs some sensor values and low and high limits (that will eventually trip alarms), as part of that query I use -

```
case when sequence=0 then value END as lowlimit, 
case when sequence=1 then value END as highlimit
```

The output from the select is -

```
status  sensor  lowlimit    highlimit

163      49      NULL          24
163      49       15          NULL
128      25      NULL          8
128      25       4           NULL
```

but I need the results to be 'concatenated' (a single row for each unique status), thus -

```
status  sensor  lowlimit    highlimit

163       49      15           24
128       25      4             8
```

so probably need something adding to the case statements, but if I use

```
max(case when sequence=0 then value END) as lowlimit, 
max(case when sequence=1 then value END) as highlimit
```

then only 1 row is output -

```
 status sensor  lowlimit    highlimit

 163     49        15          24
```

any assistance appreciated.

Regards
Active

Comment: Can you share the whole query please?

Comment: Not really, there are 8 table joins and the select statement actually has 15 elements, the only issue is the case when statement outputting on more than 1 row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  the result on the same row 
You should use a seleft join  (not case)

```
select a.status, a.sensor, a.values as lowlimit, b.value as highlimit
from my_table a 
inner join (
    select status, sensor, value from my_table 
    where sequence = 1
  ) b on a.sensor = b.sensor and a.status = b.status
where a.sequence = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output from my existing select is not a table, it is a multi- level select on 8 tables, the only issue is the output for each status is on 2 rows

Comment: i'm based  on the sample you provided .. and based  on this my answers hould be right ... anyway  if you need  both the values  on the same row, for wah i know , you should use a proper selfjoin ans suggested in my answer